# MYOB .NET SDK - Invoice creation

Tags: c#, sdk, myob

I'm not sure if anyone will be able to help me or not but I am hoping there is someone familiar with the .NET SDK for MYOB.

> The service classes accessible in the SDK provide the core HTTP
> operations available for each consumable endpoint. These include the
> following operators:
>
> Get/GetRange – HTTP GET Insert – HTTP POST Update – HTTP PUT Delete –
> HTTP DELETE

https://developer.myob.com/api/myob-business-api/arlive-sdk/dotnet_sdk/sdk-services/

The **InvoiceService** is accessed via

```
MYOB.AccountRight.SDK.Services.Sale.InvoiceService.
```

I have instantiated an InvoiceService object:

```
var invService = new InvoiceService(configuration);
```

However the InvoiceService class does not have an "Insert" function.

The API endpoint documentation suggests a "POST" is possible though: https://developer.myob.com/api/myob-business-api/v2/sale/invoice/invoice_service/

Am I using the wrong class? I unfortunately can't find any SDK documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `MYOB.AccountRight.SDK.Services.Sale.ItemInvoiceService` instead of `MYOB.AccountRight.SDK.Services.Sale.InvoiceService`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I just checked that though and there is no insert on that service either?

Comment: @Sami.C Do you use a nuget package MYOB.AccountRight.API.SDK? Which version?

Comment: the most recent version - 2022.1.392

Comment: my apologies, I am seeing the Insert method now. Thank you!